# How do I shift text on the green background next to the logo

Tags: html, css

HTML and CSS code for the given problem I want the AJTutorials on the green background after the logo, not below it.
[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS9F4.png)
[After removing display:block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV35G.png)

```css
body {
  font-family: "Comforter", cursive;
  font-family: "Cormorant", serif;
}

.Top-heading {
  background-color: rgb(160, 228, 143);
  height: 60px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.heading img {
  /*display: block;*/
  position: relative;
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.AJ {
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
}

.Tutorials {
  z-index: 2;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="Top-heading">
    <div class="heading">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="">
      <a href="#" class="AJ">AJ<span class="Tutorials">Tutorials</span></a>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever element with `display: block;` will occupy the entire available width. I'd start with removing `display: block;` from the `.heading img`.